# how custom order by with two table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i want to sort the status in approve.blade.php with Pending status is on the top and Approve status is below. Here's the thing, i want to join `fup_id` in approvals table and `id` in fups table then i want to order by `'decision' 'like' 'setuju'` in approvals table by DESC.

Comment: Please include the full relevant code.

Comment: code in controller or in model?

Comment: Just include the full code for your Laravel query (at least this much).

Comment: It is on my ApprovalController code, $fups = FUP::paginate(5); $apps = Approval::all();

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help

Answer (score 1):

you can use join query directly:

```
$fups = FUP::leftJoin('approvals', 'fups.id', '=', 'approvals.fup_id')
    ->orderByDesc("approvals.decision")
    ->orderByDesc("approvals.like")
    ->orderByDesc("approvals.setuju")
    ->paginate(5);
```